# error while creating hive table from mapr-db (hbase like)

Tags: hive, hbase, mapr

I have created a MapR-DB table in a spark code:

```
case class MyLog(count: Int, message: String)

val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Launcher").setMaster("local[2]")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val data = Seq(MyLog(3, "monmessage"))
val log_rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
log_rdd.saveToMapRDB("/tables/tablelog",createTable = true, idFieldPath = "message")
```

when I print this line from spark code I get in the console:

```
{"_id":"monmessage","count":3,"message":"monmessage"}
```

I would like to create an hive table to make select or other query on this table so I try this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE mapr_table_2(count int, message string)
     STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
     WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = "message")
     TBLPROPERTIES("hbase.table.name" = "/tables/tablelog");
```

but I get:

```
Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. java.lang.RuntimeException: MetaException(message:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException Error: the HBase columns mapping contains a badly formed column family, column qualifier specification.)
```

I took the create table query from this link :
http://maprdocs.mapr.com/home/Hive/HiveAndMapR-DBIntegration-GettingStarted.html

By the way, I don't understand what do I need to put in the line :

hbase.columns.mapping" = 
Do you have any idea how to create the table ? Thanks

Comment: What about learning some concepts about HBase -- a table is created with 1..N "Column Families" (for storage purposes); you can create/update/delete "cells" that are made of { arbitrary key, arbitrary column name in a specific CF, arbitrary value, timestamp }; in case of an update you can retain the version history for the cell; etc.

Comment: Your Spark code does not define Column Families so I guess MapR uses a default CF name; but there is no such default for Hive, so you **must** discover what is that default CF name. Run `hbase shell` then `scan '/tables/tablelog'` and observe the prefix for your "message" column name.

Comment: hi, thank you very much to answer :) when I procces scan '/tmp/tablelog' I get

ERROR: HBase api's cannot be used for MapR-DB JSON tabletype tables. Perhaps I should use binary api intead of OJAI api. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Ouch - so it's not a "HBase-like table" (what MapR calls a *binary* table). It uses different tools, different syntax, etc. Good luck.

Comment: BTW I'm not sure you can map a Hive table on a MapR-specific-JSON-DB table. The tutorial you used (cf. link) applies to MapRDB *binary* tables (which are largely compatible with HBase API).

Comment: Thanks I will try with binary table, BTW, I find in the documentation: JSON tables store data in column families, which are collections of fields that are stored together on disk.  Each table has a default column family, which is default storage for all fields in the documents of a table.